# Settings app for custom implementation of an Android Service

Tags: android

I implemented a TTS service for Android which works as expected. I can also manage its settings via the Text To Speech section of the Android Settings app.

However, on a Pixel tablet running Android 8.1, the settings app crashes for my TTS implementation with the following exception:

```
2019-02-25 10:45:46.396 5816-5816/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.android.settings, PID: 5816
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean android.content.Intent.migrateExtraStreamToClipData()' on a null object reference
    at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1742)
    at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:5168)
    at android.app.Activity.startActivityFromFragment(Activity.java:5144)
    at android.app.Activity$HostCallbacks.onStartActivityFromFragment(Activity.java:7690)
    at android.app.Fragment.startActivity(Fragment.java:1075)
    at android.app.Fragment.startActivity(Fragment.java:1054)
    at com.android.settings.tts.TextToSpeechSettings.onGearClick(TextToSpeechSettings.java:780)
    at com.android.settings.widget.GearPreference.onClick(GearPreference.java:71)
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6294)
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:24770)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:790)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
```

I could not find [any docs of what setting implementation I am required to implement for the Service](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/tts/TextToSpeechService). Any hint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I was missing is a metadata which points to the settings activity of my service (a class that extends PreferenceActivity, EngineSettings here):

In AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<service
    android:name=".MyTtsService"
    android:label="@string/app_name">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.TTS_SERVICE" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    </intent-filter>
    <meta-data android:name="android.speech.tts" android:resource="@xml/tts_engine" />
</service>
```

And tts_engine.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<tts-engine xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:settingsActivity="com.mytts.EngineSettings" />
```